# Points in common

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have the following problem:

How many points do the graphs of $4x^2-9y^2=36$ and $x^2-2x+y^2=15$ have in common?

I know that the answer is in the system of two equations, but how should I solve it?

---

Another question: when I try to set the condition of tangence between an hyperbola and an ellipse, I should state $\Delta=0$ and solve for the parameter.
The problem is: I need a solving equation, on which I calculate delta.

If I substitute $x^2$ I get a solving equation, if I substitute $y^2$ I get another one. How should I go?

Answer (score 3):

From the first equation we have:
$$y^2=\frac{4x^2-36}{9},$$
then we substitute $y^2$ in the second equation we found
$$\frac{13}{9}x^2-2x-4=0,$$
so we solve for $x$ and then we determine the suitable $y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Think geometrically - what does the two equations tell you?

Comment: The first is an hyperbola, the second is a circle. I have to solve the problem algebraically.

Comment: @Surferonthefall: For the question of points, you do not need to solve them algebraically.

Comment: I'm sorry it was part of the text problem.